# Mapping URL of domain to different folder

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, virtualhost, mod-rewrite

So I have following folder structure:

```
- web
   - SiteA
   - SiteB
   - SiteC
```

I have the Domain www.sitea.de pointing to the folder SiteA. So far so good, everything works. Now I would like to point www.sitea.de/siteb/* to the folder SiteB. The same goes for SiteC: www.sitea.de/sitec/* to SiteC.

What I have tried so far:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
# General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
DocumentRoot /web/SiteA/
ServerName www.sitea.de

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

<Directory /web/SiteA/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

  Alias /siteb "/web/SiteB/"
  <Directory "/web/SiteB/">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So far when I type www.sitea.de/siteb it calls the homepage of SiteB but without any stylesheets loading. Chrome Console return 404 on www.sitea.de/siteb/css/style.css. Even if I call www.sitea.de/siteb/contentxyz it redirects me to the "site-not-found-page" of SiteA.

From my observations it seems like nnothing after www.sitea.de/siteb/* is redirected to the folder SiteB.

Is there a way to redirect also the rest off the URL?

Comment: Do you have any reason for not having the folders structured to copy the URL structure? `web/siteA/siteB` for siteB and `/web/siteA/siteC` for siteC?

Comment: the server is shared with other admins and thats why I can't change the structure. There also links pointing already to those urls..